# How secure is file-based encryption in Android?

Tags: encryption, brute-force-attack, scrypt

I want to estimate the cost of breaking file-based encryption in Android given a password entropy. The only information I found so far is [this](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based#key-derivation):

> The stretched credential is the user credential after salting and
> stretching with the scrypt algorithm.

AFAIK, scrypt has several parameters. How do I know what parameters are used in Android? Probably, different derivatives of the Android Open Source Project use different parameters. I am interested in LineageOS.

Comment: Why not check the source code reps or Android forums. This is more a Q/A site about cryptography as a study, much less about the practical application of algorithms within devices.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Android forums are silent on this matter. In order to find it in the source code, I need to know where to look. :-) Can I just get this information from a file system header in the working instance of LineageOS? Anyway, thank you for the suggestion. I will cross-post this question to the Android Stack Exchange.

Comment: [Connection between PIN/password and encryption keys in Android](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/247954/118310)